# Serilog property outside of message template

Tags: serilog

I am currently using Serilog (Serilog.AspNetCore version 3.4.0) with a Loggly sink and I want to be able to write logs with a certain message template and properties that are not included in that template. I tried several variants but none seems to work:

```
_log.LogInformation("My message template", new {SeparateProperty = "Property value"});
_log.LogInformation(new {MyMessageTemplate = "My message template", SeparateProperty = "Property value"});
```

Where _log is an ILogger. How can I add properties to a log without having to include them in the message template?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [LogContext](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment#the-logcontext) properties.

---

#### The `LogContext`

`Serilog.Context.LogContext` can be used to dynamically add and remove properties from the ambient "execution context"; for example, all messages written during a transaction might carry the id of that transaction, and so-on.

This feature must be added to the logger at configuration-time using `.FromLogContext()`:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
```

Then, properties can be added and removed from the context using `LogContext.PushProperty()`:

```
log.Information("No contextual properties");

using (LogContext.PushProperty("A", 1))
{
    log.Information("Carries property A = 1");

    using (LogContext.PushProperty("A", 2))
    using (LogContext.PushProperty("B", 1))
    {
        log.Information("Carries A = 2 and B = 1");
    }

    log.Information("Carries property A = 1, again");
}
```

Pushing property onto the context will override any existing properties with the same name, until the object returned from `PushProperty()` is disposed, as the property `A` in the example demonstrates.

**Important:** properties *must* be popped from the context in the precise order in which they were added. Behavior otherwise is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

`ILogger<T>.BeginScope()` can do this:

```cs
using (_log.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>{
    ["SeparateProperty"] = "Property value"
}))
{
    _log.LogInformation("My message template");
}
```

See also [this explanation](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/11/ilogger-beginscope/).

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ForContext()` method:

Example:

```csharp
_log.ForContext("Request", requestToLog, true)
    .ForContext("Response", responseToLog, true)
    .Information("{method} {uri}, {durationMs}ms [HTTP {statusCode}]", requestToLog.method, requestToLog.uri, durationMs, (int)responseToLog.statusCode);
```

Event logged on [Seq](https://datalust.co/seq):

[image: example]